# Does FilterRegistrationBean use AntPathMatcher to match url patterns?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

https://www.local.myapp.com:8443/static/v1/cache/min.js

Following filter is not applied to above request. However, If I change urlPatterns to `/*` from `/**` then filter is applied. Now, I wonder for filterRegistrationBean if spring is using `antPathnMatcher` or not ?

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<WhitelistHttpMethodFilter> whitelistHttpMethodFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<WhitelistHttpMethodFilter> whitelistMethodFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        WhitelistHttpMethodFilter filter = new WhitelistHttpMethodFilter(getWhitelistedHttpMethods());

        whitelistMethodFilter.setFilter(filter);
        whitelistMethodFilter.addUrlPatterns("/**");
        whitelistMethodFilter.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        whitelistMethodFilter.setOrder(3);
        return whitelistMethodFilter;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not use `AntPathMatcher`. As suggested by [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.html#addUrlPatterns-java.lang.String...-), the syntax for the patterns is as defined in the Servlet specification:

> Add URL patterns, as defined in the Servlet specification, that the filter will be registered against.